# Tracking form field changes (is dirty) but without a Form element

Tags: jquery

In my web app I need to track changes to form fields such as input, textarea and so on. Basically I am looking for a "is dirty" plugin, preferrably for jQuery. There are plenty of them out there but they all seem to be dependent on the html having a Form element. My app doesn't use a Form element and saving data is done through Ajax, so I don't even have a submit button.

It would also be nice if the dirty flag got set when the user inputs data and NOT when the control loses focus.

Do you know of plugin that can detect changes and simply provides a callback that gets fired when anything changes but doesn't require a Form element?

Answer (score 0):

**jQuery functions you should use are .change and .each, as explained below**

You can bind the following

```
$( "input" ).change(function() {
alert( "Handler for .change() called." );
});
```

This will work for you but keep in mind that you will be executing an AJAX request for every change/key you would be pressing.

EDIT:

I suggest that on every change you collect the data and send it at once. These is achievable using .each() as follows

```
$( "input" ).change(function() {
    $('input').each(function(key)               
        formData += '&'+$('#'+this.id).attr('name')+'='+$('#'+this.id).val();   
    });
});
```

The above might have to be polished up for your needs but felt I should make it clear to give you a good idea how to move on.

You may also consider using the following ([Bind with Delay](http://www.briangrinstead.com/files/bindWithDelay/)) in conjunction with the above to avoid these multiple AJAX requests.

jQuery Documentation

[.change](http://api.jquery.com/change/)
[.each](http://api.jquery.com/each/)

Thanks

Comment: Implementing just a .change handler isn't good enough for handling dirty forms, which is why there are a lot of plugins to handle it for you.

Comment: .change is the way to go if you want to fire the event while the user is typing (and not when the element looses focuses)
PS: What exactly do you mean by "is dirty" ?

Comment: "Dirty" means that the data in the control has changed. This could happen with keypresses or pasting data. You would have to add a class to the control to indicate when it has changed and then scan the html for this class to find those controls that have changed.

Comment: oki that's clear.. therefore I really see no issue with implementing the above. As explained you would need to change according to your needs, especially the jquery selectors.
After the .change, I would add a $(this).addClass to comply with what you are saying. And then use hasClass before you collect your form data.
If you want set up a jsfiddle and I'll assist you, I did this plenty of times